# Getting webpack to ignore a file and just require the original one

Tags: node.js, webpack

I rewrote my server side code to use experimental esm imports. That means `__dirname` doesnt work anymore. To make this library consumable by non module code, I used webpack to transpile the code which strips all imports and bundles it together. However, to get around the `__dirname` problem, I have a `cjs` file that always gets loaded as commonjs module which only exports `__dirname`. However, webpack also bundles this file and destroys the meaning of __dirname (no matter which option you pass in the webpack config).

So my question: **How can I convince webpack to just require this single file while bundling everything else?**

The external option only seems to work for modules which are not loaded by path (like `require('anyModule')`) but not `require('./somefile.js')`

PS: The ignore plugin doesnt work. It just includes an error in the bundled file saying that the file cant be found

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the file (cjs ?) to be loaded 'as is' and not to be modified by webapck ? Could you do it with something like [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) and load this specific file. I am just unsure how it would connect with all the rest though

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the external option by passing a function and filtering out that specific filename and replaced it with the correct path to the file:

```
  externals: [ nodeModules, function (context, request, callback) {
    if (/dirname.cjs/.test(request)) {
      return callback(null, 'commonjs ./' + path.join('./', path.relative(__dirname, context), request).replace('\\', '/'))
    }
    callback()
  } ]
```

I am not sure if this path juggling is needed but it gets the job done